# I want to ask if there is any way to get labels with each new record.. labels like appear in gmail with new

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm working on an application where I am getting emails of users and saving them to the database. Each new entry should get a label (new), this label should disappear after reloading page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add new column as `boolean` as name `read` set dafault `false` in your working table

it will false with every data's now you can count your data

make ajax trigger call when user click on link make every column read false to true

your data is 0 now